# PHP Unable to echo ID field from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

I'm trying to print an ID from MySQL, the field loads into an array and is visible via print_r but I can't echo it or transfer it to another variable ... what am I missing?

```
if ( $_POST['section'] == "freelance" ) {
    $field_name = "promoter";
} else {
    $field_name = "connector";
}
echo $row[$field_name.'_login_ID']
```

As requested the results of var_dump($row)

```
array(13) {
   ["connector_login_id"] =>  string(2) "14"
   ["connector_type"] =>  string(10) "non-profit"
   ["unique_code"] =>  string(9) "test-t001"
   ["update_code"] =>  string(1) "N"
   ["md5ID"] =>  string(0) ""
   ["username"] =>  string(6) "bugger"
   ["connectorEmail"] =>  string(17) "gzigner@gmail.com"
   ["password"] =>  string(32) "098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6"
   ["connectorPass"] =>  string(4) "test"
   ["active"] =>  string(1) "Y"
   ["modified"] =>  string(19) "2009-08-21 15:37:22"
   ["lastlogin"] =>  string(19) "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
   ["md5email" ]=>  string(32) "051cba58da33fac6b2d18af5182079f4"
}
```

Comment: Where does `$row` come from? Can you post the results of `var_dump($row)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$row[$field_name.'_login_ID']   <-- "ID"

array(13) {
    ["connector_login_id"]      <-- "id"
```

Seems like a simple typo to me.

Alternatively, are you sure `$field_name` gets set to `'connector'`, since `'promoter_login_id'` doesn't exist in this array.

Comment: damn but that's embarrassing.  Thanks everyone who helped.

Comment: The accepted standard response seems to be *"Argh, my coffee hasn't kicked in yet."*, but *"I shouldn't have coded for 24 hours straight"* works as well. ;o)

Answer (score 0):

This is purely speculation without your code, but it's probable that the field you are trying to echo contains a hyphen, e.g. "mytable-id", considering that it does indeed show when you use print_r() to print out the entire array. If this is the case you would need to use {'mytable-id'} to get/echo it's value:

```
echo($dataArray->MyTable->{'mytable-id'});
```

***Edit**: I don't know if your code is copy and pasted, but the value you are trying to print is:

```
echo $row[$field_name.'_login_ID'];
```

instead of:

```
echo $row[$field_name.'_login_id'];
```

PHP is case-sensitive. You could also try this:

```
$field_name = $field_name.'_login_id';
echo $row[$field_name];
```

or

```
$field_name = $field_name.'_login_id';
echo $row['$field_name'];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm not using hyphens and the value still doesn't print even if I use echo $row[0].

Comment: No problem, I was merely guessing what the most obvious reason would be according to my experience. Can you please post the results of var_dump($row) as per Deceze comment on your question?

Comment: Updated possible solutions in my answer Belinda.

Comment: The last one won't work, there's no key named `'$field_name'`. :)

Comment: @deceze: AFAIK you could do echo('$field_name is having a great time'); and that would work just fine. Doesn't the same thing apply when passing it to an array?

Comment: Thanks :)  It was the uppercase "ID" that was the problem.

Comment: @Boekwurm: Yes, in *double* quotes. But `$var` and `"$var"` are identical in this case anyway, so why bother? :)